# Creating a list of points within each group of Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataset that is structured as `example_df` presented below:

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'measurement_id': np.concatenate([[0] * 300, [1] * 300]),
                           'min': np.concatenate([np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10), 
                                                  np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10)]),
                           'grp': list(np.repeat(['A', 'B'], 5)) * 60,
                           'grp2': list(np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], 10)) * 60,
                           'obj': np.array(list(range(0, 10)) * 60),
                           'x': np.random.normal(0.0, 10.0, 600),
                           'y': np.random.normal(50.0, 40.0, 600)})
```

I also have a function that takes a list of groups of points as input and perform some calculations. I'd like to prepare my data and create a list of list of points within grouped data frame.

My current solution is as follows:

```
def df_to_points(df):
    points = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        points.append(tuple(row))
    return(points)

res = example_df \
    .groupby(['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp']) \
    .apply(lambda x: [df_to_points(g[['x', 'y']]) for _, g in x.groupby('grp2')])

res.head(5)
measurement_id  min  grp
0               0    A      [[(7.435996920897324, 63.64844826366264), (-9....
                1    B      [[(-10.213911323779579, 108.64263032884301), (...
                2    A      [[(6.004534743892181, 38.11898691750269), (12....
                3    B      [[(-11.486905682289555, 68.26172126981378), (-...
                4    A      [[(7.5612638943199295, 28.756743327333556), (-...
```

where each row of `res` series looks like this:

```
[[(7.435996920897324, 63.64844826366264),
  (-9.722976872232584, 11.831678494223155),
  (10.809492206072777, 82.9238481225157),
  (-7.918248246978473, 58.46902598333271)],
 [(6.270634566510545, 59.10653240815831),
  (-5.765185730532471, 22.232739287056663),
  (-13.129531349093371, 85.02932179274353)],
 [(0.6686875099768917, 60.634711491838786),
  (-7.373072676442981, 30.897262347426693),
  (-11.489744246260528, 6.834296232736001)]]
```

The problem is that my original DataFrame has few millions of rows and it feels like this solution could benefit from some optimisation.

Current runtime of the example is:

```
%timeit res = example_df \
    .groupby(['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp']) \
    .apply(lambda x: [df_to_points(g[['x', 'y']]) for _, g in x.groupby('grp2')])
289 ms ± 1.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Therefore, my question are:

1. will replacing list of tuples with `numpy` multidimensional arrays improve the performance?
2. are there any significant bottlenecks that should be avoided in order to increase speed up?

@Edit: An example with various number of objects within groups defined by `grp`

```
example_df2 =  pd.DataFrame({'measurement_id': np.concatenate([[0] * 300, [1] * 300]),
                           'min': np.concatenate([np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10), 
                                                  np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10)]),
                           'grp': list(np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], [4, 4, 2])) * 60,
                           'grp2': list(np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], 10)) * 60,
                           'obj': np.array(list(range(0, 10)) * 60),
                           'x': np.random.normal(0.0, 10.0, 600),
                           'y': np.random.normal(50.0, 40.0, 600)})
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `.pivot_table()` and as `aggfunc=` simple `list`:

```
example_df['combined'] = example_df[['x', 'y']].values.tolist()
example_df = example_df.pivot_table(index=['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp'], columns=['grp2'], values=['combined'], aggfunc=list)
example_df['res'] = example_df.values.tolist()
example_df = example_df.drop(columns=['combined'])
```

Prints:

```
                                                                      res
grp2                                                                     
measurement_id min grp                                                   
0              0   A    [[[0.9303000896627107, 42.806752849742715], [-...
               1   B    [[[-18.605643711859955, 117.83261611194004], [...
               2   A    [[[-7.304055455430749, 18.06452177236371], [-1...
...
```

---

Benchmark with `timeit`:

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'measurement_id': np.concatenate([[0] * 300, [1] * 300]),
                           'min': np.concatenate([np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10),
                                                  np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10)]),
                           'grp': list(np.repeat(['A', 'B'], 10)) * 30,
                           'grp2': list(np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], 10)) * 60,
                           'obj': np.array(list(range(0, 10)) * 60),
                           'x': np.random.normal(0.0, 10.0, 600),
                           'y': np.random.normal(50.0, 40.0, 600)})

def get_df():
    return example_df.copy()

def solution_1():
    def df_to_points(df):
        points = []
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            points.append(tuple(row))
        return(points)

    example_df = get_df()
    res = example_df \
        .groupby(['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp']) \
        .apply(lambda x: [df_to_points(g[['x', 'y']]) for _, g in x.groupby('grp2')])
    return res

def solution_2():
    example_df = get_df()
    example_df['combined'] = example_df[['x', 'y']].values.tolist()
    example_df = example_df.pivot_table(index=['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp'], columns=['grp2'], values=['combined'], aggfunc=list)
    example_df['res'] = example_df.values.tolist()
    example_df = example_df.drop(columns=['combined'])
    return example_df

t1 = timeit(lambda: solution_1(), number=100)
t2 = timeit(lambda: solution_2(), number=100)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
21.74300919502275
3.124330924008973
```

---

EDIT: With updated question, you can do this:

```
example_df['combined'] = example_df[['x', 'y']].values.tolist()
example_df = example_df.pivot_table(index=['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp'], columns=['grp2'], values=['combined'], aggfunc=list)
example_df.apply(lambda x: list(x[x.notna()]), axis=1)
```

Benchmark with:

```
from timeit import timeit

example_df = pd.DataFrame({'measurement_id': np.concatenate([[0] * 300, [1] * 300]),
                           'min': np.concatenate([np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10),
                                                  np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10)]),
                           'grp': list(np.repeat(['A', 'B'], 5)) * 60,
                           'grp2': list(np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], 10)) * 60,
                           'obj': np.array(list(range(0, 10)) * 60),
                           'x': np.random.normal(0.0, 10.0, 600),
                           'y': np.random.normal(50.0, 40.0, 600)})

example_df =  pd.DataFrame({'measurement_id': np.concatenate([[0] * 300, [1] * 300]),
                           'min': np.concatenate([np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10),
                                                  np.repeat(range(0, 30), 10)]),
                           'grp': list(np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], [4, 4, 2])) * 60,
                           'grp2': list(np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], 10)) * 60,
                           'obj': np.array(list(range(0, 10)) * 60),
                           'x': np.random.normal(0.0, 10.0, 600),
                           'y': np.random.normal(50.0, 40.0, 600)})

def get_df():
    return example_df.copy()

def solution_1():
    def df_to_points(df):
        points = []
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            points.append(tuple(row))
        return(points)

    example_df = get_df()
    res = example_df \
        .groupby(['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp']) \
        .apply(lambda x: [df_to_points(g[['x', 'y']]) for _, g in x.groupby('grp2')])
    return res

def solution_2():
    example_df = get_df()
    example_df['combined'] = example_df[['x', 'y']].values.tolist()
    example_df = example_df.pivot_table(index=['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp'], columns=['grp2'], values=['combined'], aggfunc=list)
    return example_df.apply(lambda x: list(x[x.notna()]), axis=1)

t1 = timeit(lambda: solution_1(), number=100)
t2 = timeit(lambda: solution_2(), number=100)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
45.391786905995104
13.506823723029811
```

Comment: definitely better than groupby+apply

Comment: Interesting solution. Unfortunetely, it doesn't generalise well to the case with variable number of objects within groups defined by `grp` as it produces `NaN` values.. Additionally, each element of 'res' column is a `Series`, not intended list; please see the output of `example_df.iloc[0]['res']` and how it differs from my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the whole dataframe to a numpy array before iterate it with just `array = np.array(df)`. It will sure improve the performance. 
You can also use the multi thread module to parallel process and gain performance as well.
You can also use the pandas  `.apply()` instead of using `.iterrows()`

Comment: Could you elaborate, especially on `numpy` solution?

Answer (score 0):

One slight optimisation would be:

```
def df_to_points(df): 
    return [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
```

Then you get

```
In [59]: %timeit res = example_df \ 
    ...:     .groupby(['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp']) \ 
    ...:     .apply(lambda x: [df_to_points(g[['x', 'y']]) for _, g in x.groupby('grp2')])                                        
241 ms ± 14.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

as opposed to (with the original definition of `df_to_points`)

```
In [58]: %timeit res = example_df \ 
    ...:     .groupby(['measurement_id', 'min', 'grp']) \ 
    ...:     .apply(lambda x: [df_to_points(g[['x', 'y']]) for _, g in x.groupby('grp2')])                                        
284 ms ± 10.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```